# What is the best way to use Git for app version, modules, client installations and customizations?

Tags: git

I have the following situation and I need sone guidelines on how to use git as optimal as possible. I have a web application developed in laravel. It will be used by multiple clients as standalone installation. This application has a core with different version (releasese) and a bunch of modules (not laravel modules, my own modules of features inside the application) each with their own versions.

When installing it to a client I select which modules will be used and create a build and install it. Appart from that each client will need customization. I developed the application in such a way that all customizations will be inside a separate folder (something like hooks) and completly independent of the core, so that i can override the core without affecting the customizations.

How can I mantain via git the core, the modules, client’s instalations and client’s customizations somehow independently but in the same time linked so that when i create a new version of the core or for a module I can push it to all client’s git/installations (not necesarily automatic)? How can I keep track of versions per core and per modules so I can compare and know what version is each client running on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you just make a new branch per client and have modules be:

[Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

Submodules could have their own per customer branches as well if you wanna go that route